# i have a table where i can activate and deactvate users,it works but i want to activate and deactivate a users using ajax so the page won't refresh

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

i have no idea of ajax but my code looks like this. i want the onclick action in the link to be able to toogle activate and deactivate users using ajax and i don't want the page to refresh

> ```
> <a href="'.url('admin/Users/view_users/'.$id.'/'.$data.'').'"
> data-toogle="tooltip"  title="click to toogle" onClick="Refresh"
> class="'.$statBg.'">'.$status.'</a>
> ```
>
> to be able to toogle activate and deactivate users using ajax and i dont want the page to refresh

```
 public function AjaxRefresh(){

    $table = '<table class="table table-bordered">
              <tr style="text-align: center;">
              <th>Role</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
              <tbody>';
    $users = User::latest('id')->get();
    foreach($users as $user) {

        $nm = $user->name;
        $id = $user->id;
        $data = $user->status==1?0:1;
        $email = $user->email;
        $status = $user->status == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive";
        $online = $user->active_user == 1 ? "Online" : "Offline";
        $statBg=$user->status == 1 ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger";
        $onlineBg=$user->active_user == 1 ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger";

        $table .= '<tr style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                    <td>' . Role::find($user->role_id)->role_designation . '</td>
                    <td>' . $nm . '</td><td>' . $email . '</td>
                    <td >
                    <!--<span class="'.$statBg.'">' . $status . '</span>-->
                    <a href="'.url('admin/Users/view_users/'.$id.'/'.$data.'').'" data-toogle="tooltip"  title="click to toogle" onClick="Refresh" class="'.$statBg.'">'.$status.'</a>
                    &nbsp;
                    <span   class="'.$onlineBg.'">' . $online . '</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$user->id}}" class=" btn-primary xs">View</a>
                            <a href="'.url('admin/Doctors/edit/'.$user->id.'').'" class=" btn-info xs">Edit</a>
                            <a href="'.url('admin/Doctors/delete/doctor/'.$user->id.'').'" class=" btn-danger xs">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</tbody></table>';

    exit ($table);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we have many things to take a look at here, before I can give you a good answer.

Some introductory points:

- you should not create the table on the server and return it as a string;
- you should not use the `exit` function, but instead search for something more appropriate;

I will not just copy the AJAX definition, but I will try to give you some advices on what to do. The topic to cover is very large here.

My advices here are:

- first of all, separate the backend from the frontend.

**Backend**

You'll have to expose your data in a more useful output format. JSON could be a good idea as it is used everywhere today. Also, Laravel automatically converts models collections, and many other type of data, to json.

Let's say you have something like

```
return User::all();
```

in your controller, you will automatically get something like

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "email@email.com",
    },
    ...
]
```

and so on.

**Frontend**

You will not need something extraordinary if you're just learning. Take a look to [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), more specifically to the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. You'll need to call it from your page, client-side.

If you have no idea about what AJAX is, however, it will be difficult to move forward significantly.

Cheers! :) Hope this helps as an introduction.